# Times Tables Iteration

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to use for loops in python to create a times tables. After every times table, i want it to go up by one. For example, after 2 i want it to say 3. This code below:

```
for a in range (1,13):
  for b in range (1,13):
    print(a,"*",b,"=",a*b)
  for times_tables in range (1,13):
      print(times_tables,"times tables!")
```

When I run it this is my result:

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
1 * 4 = 4
1 * 5 = 5
1 * 6 = 6
1 * 7 = 7
1 * 8 = 8
1 * 9 = 9
1 * 10 = 10
1 * 11 = 11
1 * 12 = 12
1 times tables!
2 times tables!
3 times tables!
4 times tables!
5 times tables!
6 times tables!
7 times tables!
8 times tables!
9 times tables!
10 times tables!
11 times tables!
12 times tables!
```

I want it to just say one, and on the next iteration go to two. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You just need some rearrangements to make it work:

```
for a in range (1,13):
    print(a,"times tables!")
    for b in range (1,13):
        print(a,"*",b,"=",a*b)
```

This prints the name of the table, then the table, for each table in range (as specified by `a`).

In the beginning, it is worth going through loops like these with a pencil/paper first, write them down for a first couple cases and things will be clear. Here your inner loop evaluates everything in `b` range for every element in the outer loop. In your original example you had another loop right after - so you end up printing all table names for every element `a`. Instead, you just wanted to print the title for every `a` upfront which is the case now.

Comment: Thank you for your help @atru!